# Checking If A Vector Contains Any Element Greater Than Zero

Tags: c, vector, avx

I will be thankful if somebody can help in writing a function that receives an AVX vector and checks if it contains any element greater than zero ..

I have written the following code but it is not optimal because it stores the elements and then manipulate it.. the vector should be checked as a whole.

```
int check(__m256 vector)
{
  float * temp;
  posix_memalign ((void **) &temp, 32, 8 * sizeof(float));    
  _mm256_store_ps( temp, vector );

  int flag=0;
  for(int k=0; k<8; k++)
  {
    flag= ( (temp[k]>0) ? 1 : 0 );
    if (flag==1) return 1;
  }

  free( temp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's this document called the Intel Software Developer manual which you should grab. When you look at it, you'll see in Volume B, Chapter 3 a list of all instructions as well the intrinsics you can use for each. Here you want `__m256 vcmp = _mm256_cmp_ps(_mm256_setzero_ps(), x, _CMP_LT_OQ)`, followed by `int cmp = _mm256_movemask_ps(vcmp)` to pick out and pack together the comparison results. If `cmp = 0xFF`, your condition is satisfied.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist - that would qualify as a very relevant answer, I think.

Comment: @ryyker I suppose so but I could have sworn a variant of this had already been asked and was looking for it. I recall in a distant past an SSE variant of this, but perhaps it was checking equality to 0.

Comment: @MROF I just realized that w.r.t. my comment above, the correct comparison to find if _any_ element is >0 is `cmp != 0`, not `cmp == 0xFF` which finds if _all_ elements >0.

Comment: It is working ^_^   Many thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: The `return 1` path leaks the `temp` buffer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to branch on the result, it's usually fewer uops to use the "traditional" compare / movemask / integer-test, like you would with SSE1.

```
__m256 vcmp = _mm256_cmp_ps(_mm256_setzero_ps(), x, _CMP_LT_OQ);
int cmp = _mm256_movemask_ps(vcmp);
if (cmp)
    return 1;
```

This typically compiles to something like

```
vcmplt_oqps  ymm2, ymm0, ymm1
vpmovmskb    eax, ymm2

test         eax,eax
jnz      .true_branch
```

Those are all single-uop instructions, and test/jnz macro-fuse on Intel and AMD CPUs that support AVX, so this is only 3 total uops (on Intel).

See [Agner Fog's instruction tables + microarch guide](http://agner.org/optimize/), and other guides linked from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

---

You can also use PTEST, but it's less efficient for this case.  See [_mm_testc_ps and _mm_testc_pd vs _mm_testc_si128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790710/mm-testc-ps-and-mm-testc-pd-vs-mm-testc-si128)

Without AVX, `ptest` handy for checking if a register is all-zero without needing extra instructions to copy it (since it sets integer flags directly).  But since it's 2 uops, and can't macro-fuse with a `jcc` branch instruction, it's actually worse than the above:

```
// don't use, sub-optimal
__m256 vcmp = _mm256_cmp_ps(_mm256_setzero_ps(), x, _CMP_LT_OQ);
if (!_mm256_testz_si256(vcmp, vcmp)) {
    return 1;
}
```

The `testz` intrinsic is `PTEST`.  It sets the ZF and CF flags directly based on the results of AND and AND NOT of its args.  The testz intrinsic is true when `vcmp` has any non-zero bits.  (which it will only when `vcmpps` puts some there.)

`VPTEST` with ymm regs is available with just AVX.  AVX2 isn't required even though it looks like a vector-integer instruction.

This will compile to something like

```
vcmplt_oqps  ymm2, ymm0, ymm1
vptest       ymm2, ymm2
jnz      .true_branch
```

Probably smaller code-size than the above, but this is actually 4 uops instead of 3.  If you were using `setnz` or `cmovnz`, macro-fusion wouldn't be a factor, so `ptest` would be break-even.  As I mentioned above, the main use-case for `ptest` is when you can use it without a compare instruction, and without AVX.

The alternative for checking a vector for all-zero (`pcmpeqb xmm0,xmm1` / `pmovmskb eax, xmm1` / `test eax,eax`) has to destroy one of the input vectors without AVX, so it will require an extra `movdqa` instruction to copy if you still need both after the test.

---

### `ptest` floating point bit-hacks

I think for this specific test, it might be possible to skip the compare instruction and use `vptest` directly to see if there are any `float` elements with their sign bit unset, but some non-zero bits elsewhere.

**Actually no, that idea can't work, because it doesn't respect element boundaries**.  It couldn't tell the difference between a vector with a positive element vs. a vector with a `+0.0` element (sign bit clear) and another element that was negative (other bits set).

`vptest` sets [CF=`bool(~src1 & src2)` and ZF=`(src1 & src2)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712243/can-ptest-be-used-to-test-if-two-registers-are-both-zero-or-some-other-condition).  I was thinking that src1=`set1(0x7FFFFFFF)` could tell us something useful about sign bits and non-sign bits, which we could test with a condition that checks CF and ZF.  For example [`ja`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/Jcc.html): CF=0 and ZF=0.  There actually isn't an x86 condition that's only true with CF=1 *and* ZF=0, though, so that's another problem.

Also `NaN > 0` is false, but NaN has some set bits.  (exponent all-ones, mantissa non-zero, sign-bit = don't care so there can be +NaN and -NaN).  If that was the only problem, this would still be useful in cases where NaN-handling isn't required.