# _mm_testc_ps and _mm_testc_pd vs _mm_testc_si128

Tags: c, x86, simd, avx, sse4

As you know, the first two are AVX-specific intrinsics and the second is a SSE4.1 intrinsic. Both sets of intrinsics can be used to check for equality of 2 floating-point vectors. My specific use case is:

- `_mm_cmpeq_ps` or `_mm_cmpeq_pd`, followed by
- `_mm_testc_ps` or `_mm_testc_pd` on the result, with an appropriate mask

But AVX provides equivalents for "legacy" intrinsics, so I might be able to use `_mm_testc_si128`, after a cast of the result to `__m128i`. My questions are, which of the two use cases results in better performance and where I can find out what legacy SSE instructions are provided by AVX.

Comment: Apologies if you're already aware of this, but you do know that, in general, comparing floats for equality is usually a bad idea, right ?

Comment: Also note that `_mm_cmpeq_ps`/`_mm_cmpeq_pd` are SSE2, not AVX, so I don't see any AVX-specific aspect to your question ?

Comment: I know comparing floats for equality is usually bad, but not always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops, I didn't read the question carefully.  You're talking about using these after a `cmpeqps`.  They're always slower than `movmskps / test` if you already have a mask.  `cmpps` / `ptest / jcc` is 4 uops.  `cmpps` / `movmskps eax, xmm0` / `test eax,eax` / `jnz` is 3 uops.  (test/jnz fuse into a single uop).  Also, none of the instructions are multi-uop, so no decode bottlenecks.

Only use `ptest` / `vtestps/pd` when you can take full advantage of the AND or ANDN operation to avoid an earlier step.  I've posted answers before where I compared `ptest` vs. an alternative.  I think I did find one case once where `ptest` was a win, but it's hard to use.  Yup, [found it: someone wanted an FP compare that was true for NaN == NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951714/simd-instructions-for-floating-point-equality-comparison-with-nan-nan/34955804#34955804).  It's one of the only times I've ever found a use for the carry flag result of `ptest`.

If the high element of a compare result is "garbage", then you can still ignore it cheaply with `movmskps`:

```
_mm_movemask_ps(vec) & 0b0111 == 0  // tests for none of the first three being true
```

This is totally free.  The x86 `test` instruction works a lot like `ptest`: You can use it with an immediate mask instead of to test a register against itself.  (It might have a tiny cost: one extra byte of machine code, because `test cl, 3` is one byte longer than `test ecx, ecx`, but they run identically.  Or `test eax, 3` is 3 bytes longer than `test eax,eax` (no test r32,imm8 form), but `test al, 3` is also 2 bytes because AL,imm8 encodings have short forms.)

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki for links to guides (Agner Fog's guide is good for perf analysis at the instruction level).  There's an AVX version of *every* legacy SSE instruction, but some are only 128 bits wide.  They all get an extra operand (so the dest doesn't have to be one of the src regs), which saves on `mov` instructions to copy registers.

---

Answer to a question you didn't ask:

Neither `_mm_testc_ps` nor `_mm_testc_si128` can be used to compare floats for equality.  `vtestps` is like `ptest`, but only operates on the sign bits of each float element.

They all compute `(~x) & y` (on sign bits or on the full register), which doesn't tell you whether they're equal, or even whether the sign bits are equal.

Note that even checking for bitwise equality of floats (with `pcmpeqd`) isn't the same as `cmpeqps` (which implements C's `==` operator), because `-0.0` isn't bitwise equal to `0.0`.  And two bitwise-identical NaNs aren't equal to each other.  The comparison is unordered (which means not equal) if either or both operand is `NaN`.

Comment: I see, sometimes I need to make use of the mask, for example, when I only use a part of the register (say 3 out of 4, or 2 out of 4). This is the use case where the mask becomes useful, so that I don't need to do an additional AND on the `movmskps` result.

Comment: @user1095108: you can mask the result of `movmskps`.   e.g. `_mm_movemask_ps(vec) & 0b0111 == 0b0111` tests for all of the first three elements being true, without caring about the 4th.  `_mm_movemask_ps(vec) & 0b0111 == 0` tests for none of the first three being true, and is totally free.  (The x86 `test` instruction works a lot like `ptest`: You can use it with an immediate mask instead of to test a register against itself.)

Comment: How about `_mm_movemask_epi8` after the compare? Is that better than `_mm_movemask_ps`?

Comment: @user1095108: no, it has no new information, and there's possibly a bypass delay for sending float data to an integer instruction on some CPUs.  Using it just means you need to repeat each bit 4 or 8 times in your mask, which could increase code size (`test eax, 3` can use an imm8 for the `3`, but `test eax, 0b0000111111111111` needs to use the `test eax, imm32` encoding: 5 bytes total).  So it's larger code size with no advantage, and possible disadvantage.  Generally only use `movemask_epi8` after packed integer compares, esp. if the element size was smaller than 4B.

Comment: Or of course for bithack stuff where you can do something with the high bit of every byte, even when it's not a comparison result.

Comment: Ok, final question, where can I gain info about the uops (microops?) you mention? I'd like to do my own uop counts.

Comment: I already linked the x86 tag wiki in my answer :P  To really understand when latency vs. throughput vs. total uops matters, and when there are other delays you have to account for, you need to read and understand Agner Fog's microarchitecture guide for the CPU you're tuning for.  Fortunately SnB-family CPUs (with their uop cache and loop buffer) make uop counting fairly directly useful.  On other uarches, decode is more often a bottleneck than the pipeline issue width.  But the frontend matters, esp. when pushing over 3 uops per clock.  Then it's trial and error with insn ordering/alignment.