# Can PTEST be used to test if two registers are both zero or some other condition?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, intrinsics, sse4

What can you do with [SSE4.1 `ptest`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PTEST.html) other than testing if a single register is all-zero?

Can you use a combination of SF and CF to test anything useful about two unknown input registers?

What is PTEST good for?  You'd think it would be good for checking the result of a packed-compare (like PCMPEQD or CMPPS), but at least on Intel CPUs, [it costs more uops to compare-and-branch using PTEST + JCC than with PMOVMSK(B/PS/PD) + macro-fused CMP+JCC.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790710/mm-testc-ps-and-mm-testc-pd-vs-mm-testc-si128)

See also [Checking if TWO SSE registers are not both zero without destroying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623050/checking-if-two-sse-registers-are-not-both-zero-without-destroying-them)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, unless I'm missing something clever, `ptest` with two unknown registers is generally not useful for checking some property about both of them.  (Other than obvious stuff you'd already want a bitwise-AND for, like intersection between two bitmaps).

To test two registers for both being all-zero, OR them together and PTEST that against itself.

---

`ptest xmm0, xmm1` produces two results:

- ZF = is `xmm0 & xmm1` all-zero?
- CF = is `(~xmm0) & xmm1` all-zero?  (1 if all the set bits in XMM1 are set in XMM0)

**If the second vector is all-zero, the flags don't depend at all on the bits in the first vector.**

It may be useful to think of the "is-all-zero" checks as a `NOT(bitwise horizontal-OR())` of the AND and ANDNOT results.  But probably not, because that's too many steps for my brain to think through easily.  That sequence of vertical-AND and then horizontal-OR does maybe make it easier to understand why PTEST doesn't tell you much about a combination of two unknown registers, just like the integer TEST instruction.

Here's a truth table for a 2-bit `ptest a,mask`.  Hopefully this helps in thinking about mixes of zeros and ones with 128b inputs.

Note that `CF(a,mask) == ZF(~a,mask)`.

```
a    mask     ZF    CF
00   00       1     1
01   00       1     1
10   00       1     1
11   00       1     1

00   01       1     0
01   01       0     1
10   01       1     0
11   01       0     1

00   10       1     0
01   10       1     0
10   10       0     1
11   10       0     1

00   11       1     0
01   11       0     0
10   11       0     0
11   11       0     1
```

---

[Intel's intrinsics guide lists 2 interesting intrinsics for it](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,FMA,Other&expand=3236,3233,5453,5453&text=ptest).  Note the naming of the args: `a` and `mask` are a clue that they tell you about the parts of `a` selected by a known AND-mask.

- `_mm_test_mix_ones_zeros (__m128i a, __m128i mask)`: returns `(ZF == 0 && CF == 0)`
- `_mm_test_all_zeros (__m128i a, __m128i mask)`: returns `ZF`

There's also the more simply-named versions:

- `int _mm_testc_si128 (__m128i a, __m128i b)`: returns `CF`.  (As Microsoft docs [helpfully point out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb513983(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#return-value), this is `1` if all the bits set in `b` are set in `a`; otherwise `0`.)
- `int _mm_testnzc_si128 (__m128i a, __m128i b)`: returns `(ZF == 0 && CF == 0)`
- `int _mm_testz_si128 (__m128i a, __m128i b)`: returns `ZF` (The intersection is zero.)

There are AVX2 `__m256i` versions of those intrinsics, but the guide only lists the all_zeros and mix_ones_zeros alternate-name versions for `__m128i` operands.

If you want to test some other condition from C or C++, you should use `testc` and `testz` with the same operands, and hope that your compiler realizes that it only needs to do one PTEST, and hopefully even use a single JCC, SETCC, or CMOVCC to implement your logic.  (I'd recommend checking the asm, at least for the compiler you care about most.)

---

Note that `_mm_testz_si128(v, set1(0xff))` is always the same as `_mm_testz_si128(v,v)`, because that's how AND works.  But that's not true for the CF result.

**You can check for a vector being all-ones** using

```
bool is_all_ones = _mm_testc_si128(v, _mm_set1_epi8(0xff));
```

This is probably no faster (but smaller code-size) than a `_mm_cmpeq_epi8` against a vector of all-ones, with the usual `_mm_movemask_epi8() == 0xffff`, at least if you're branching on it so the scalar `cmp` is free, fusing with the `jcc`, so both ways are 3 total uops including the (`cmp`)/`jcc`.  Except on Zen 1 & 2 where `ptest` is only 1 uop instead of 2 on other CPUs, then it has an advantage: https://uops.info/.  It doesn't avoid the need for a vector constant in this case.

PTEST does have the advantage that it doesn't destroy either input operand, even without AVX.