# What are _mm256_testc_pd, _mm256_testz_pd, _mm256_testnzc_pd for?

Tags: x86, sse, simd, intrinsics, avx

I am trying to understand the `_mm256_testc_pd`, `_mm256_testz_pd`, and `_mm256_testnzc_pd` intrinsics, and I have a hard time understanding them.

To analyze `_mm256_testc_pd`, I have identified the following cases (`a` is the first, `b` the second `__mm256d` argument`):

- If *all* packed doubles in `b` are > 0, then `ZF=1`, `CF=1`, except:
- If *one* packed double in each `a` and `b` are *mutally < 0*, then `ZF=0`.
- If *one* packed double in each `!a` and `b` are *mutually < 0*, then `CF=0`.

In other words, a value of `ZF=1` tells me that either a) `b` is entirely positive, or b) that for those doubles in `b` that are not positive, there is a matching double in `a` that is negative. A value of `CF=1` tells me that either c) `b` is entirely positive, or d) that for those doubles in `b` that are not positive, there is a matching double in in `!a` that is negative.

Have I understood this correctly? I am a bit confused by this. What's the point of this check? What would I use these intrinsics for?

Comment: The most common use case is testing the result of a compare operation, where the result elements are either all 1 or all 0 (so testing the sign bit is sufficient) - this enables you to implement predicates such as "all equal" or "any greater than" etc, using the `testz` intrinsic. (I've never found a use for any of the other variants).

Comment: @PaulR: Might as well move that to an answer.

Comment: @JasonR: yes, you're right - I got carried away with what was originally just going to be a short comment. ;-)

Comment: Usually you use `vptest` or `vtestpd` with one operand being a constant mask, not two variables.  e.g. to check for any element being negative (having its sign bit set).  Related: [Can PTEST be used to test if two registers are both zero or some other condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43712244).

Answer (score 2):

The most common use case is testing the result of a compare operation, where the result elements from the comparison are either all 1 or all 0 (so testing the sign bit is sufficient) - this enables you to implement predicates such as "all equal" or "any greater than" etc, using the `_mm*_testz_p*` intrinsic.

I've never found a use for any of the other variants.