# Check that at least 1 element is true in each of multiple vectors of compare results - horizontal OR then AND

Tags: sse, simd, intrinsics, altivec, spu

I'm looking for an SSE Bitwise OR between components of same vector.  (Editor's note: this is potentially an X-Y problem, see below for the real comparison logic.)

I am porting some SIMD logic from [SPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_(microprocessor)) intrinsics. It has an instruction

```
spu_orx(a)
```

Which according to the [docs](https://www.lri.fr/~lacas/ComputerArchitecture/SPU_language_extensions_v20.pdf)

> spu_orx: OR word across d = spu_orx(a) The four word elements of
>   vector a are logically Ored. The result is returned in word element 0
>   of vector d. All other elements (1,2,3) of d are assigned a value of
>   zero.

How can I do that with SSE 2 - 4  involving minimum instruction? `_mm_or_ps` is what I got here.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the scenario from SPU based code:

```
qword res =  spu_orx(spu_or(spu_fcgt(x, y), spu_fcgt(z, w)))
```

So it first ORs two 'greater' comparisons, then ORs its result.
Later couples of those results are ANDed to get final comparison value.

This is effectively doing `(A||B||C||D||E||F||G||H) && (I||J||K||L||M||N||O||P) && ...` where A..D are the 4x 32-bit elements of the `fcgt(x,y)` and so on.

Obviously vertical `_mm_or_ps` of `_mm_cmp_ps` results is a good way to reduce down to 1 vector, but then what?  Shuffle + OR, or something else?

**UPDATE 1**

Regarding "but then what?" 
I perform

```
     qword res =  spu_orx(spu_or(spu_fcgt(x, y), spu_fcgt(z, w)))
```

On SPU it goes like this:

```
 qword aRes  = si_and(res, res1);
 qword aRes1 = si_and(aRes, res2);
 qword aRes2 = si_and(aRes1 , res3);
 return si_to_uint(aRes2 );
```

several times on different inputs,then AND those all into a single result,which is finally cast to integer  0 or 1 (false/true test)

Comment: Are you interested in exactly that operation, or do you need it, e.g., to determine if any bit is set (e.g., after a compare instructions)?

Comment: SSE/AVX doesn't have many horizontal operations, and most of the ones that exist are inefficient.  What do you *actually* need?  If it's branching on a vector compare result, use `_mm_movemask_ps(v) != 0` to check for any element having its high bit set.

Comment: @chtz   second,I will add an example

Comment: So your vector elements are compare results.  And what you really want is SIMD (`vx[0] > vy[0]` || vx[1]>vy[1] || vz[0]>vw[0] || vz[1]>vw[1])  AND (... || ...)` regardless of how that's evaluated.  Yeah we do need horizontal OR before we can a vertical AND, so either SIMD shuffle+OR, psadbw, or `movemask` and integer stuff.

Comment: Ok, if you eventually want a booleanized 0/1 integer, PTEST -> scalar AND is probably good.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question well, but maybe the idea [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vNJAsA), is also of interest for update 1 of your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### **[SSE4.1 PTEST](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ptest) `bool any_nonzero = !_mm_testz_si128(v,v);`**

That would be a good way to horizontal OR + booleanize a vector into a 0/1 integer.  It will compile to multiple instructions, and `ptest same,same` is 2 uops on its own.  But once you have the result as a scalar integer, scalar `AND` is even cheaper than any vector instruction, and you can branch on the result directly because it sets integer flags.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
bool any_nonzero_bit(__m128i v) {
    return !_mm_testz_si128(v,v);
}
```

[On Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0Abool+any_nonzero(__m128i+v)+%7B%0A++++return+!!_mm_testz_si128(v,v)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g91,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'-O3+-march%3Dnehalem',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang800,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:eigen,ver:trunk)),options:'-O3+-march%3Dnehalem',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+8.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) with gcc9.1 -O3 -march=nehalem:

```
any_nonzero(long long __vector(2)):
    ptest   xmm0, xmm0                        # 2 uops
    setne   al                                # 1 uop with false dep on old value of RAX
    ret
```

This is only 3 uops on Intel for a horizontal OR into a single bit in an integer register.  AMD Ryzen `ptest` is only 1 uop so it's even better.

The only risk here is if gcc or clang creates false dependencies by not xor-zeroing `eax` before doing a `setcc` into AL.  Usually gcc is pretty fanatical about spending extra uops to break false dependencies so I don't know why it doesn't here.  (I did check with `-march=skylake` and `-mtune=generic` in case it was relying on Nehalem partial-register renaming for `-march=nehalem`.  Even `-march=znver1` didn't get it to xor-zero EAX before the ptest.)

It would be nice if we could avoid the `_mm_or_ps` and have PTEST do all the work.  But even if we consider inverting the comparisons, the vertical-AND / horizontal-OR behaviour doesn't let us check something about all 8 elements of 2 vectors, or about *any* of those 8 elements.

e.g. [Can PTEST be used to test if two registers are both zero or some other condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712243/can-ptest-be-used-to-test-if-two-registers-are-both-zero-or-some-other-condition)

```
  // NOT USEFUL
 // 1 if all the vertical pairs AND to zero.
 // but 0 if even one vertical AND result is non-zero
_mm_testz_si128( _mm_castps_si128(_mm_cmpngt_ps(x,y)), 
                 _mm_castps_si128(_mm_cmpngt_ps(z,w)));
```

I mention this only to rule it out and save you the trouble of considering this optimization idea.  (@chtz suggested it in comments.  Inverting the comparison is a good idea that can be useful for other ways of doing things.)

---

#### Without SSE4.1 / delaying the horizontal OR

We might be able to delay horizontal ORing / booleanizing until after combining some results from multiple vectors.  This makes combining more expensive (`imul` or something), but saves 2 uops in the vector -> integer stage vs. PTEST.

x86 has cheap vector mask->integer bitmap with `_mm_movemask_ps`.  Especially if you ultimately want to branch on the result, this might be a good idea.  (But x86 doesn't have a `||` instruction that booleanizes its inputs either so you can't just `&` the movemask results).

One thing you can do is integer *multiply* `movemask` results: `x * y` is non-zero iff both inputs are non-zero.  Unlike `x & y` which can be false for `0b0101 &`0b1010`for example.  (Our inputs are 4-bit movemask results and`unsigned` is 32-bit so we have some room before we overflow).  AMD Bulldozer family has an integer multiply that isn't fully pipelined so this could be a bottleneck on old AMD CPUs.  Using just 32-bit integers is also good for some low-power CPUs with slow 64-bit multiply.

This might be good if throughput is more of a bottleneck than latency, although `movmskps` can only run on one port.

I'm not sure if there are any cheaper integer operations that let us recover the logical-AND result later.  Adding doesn't work; the result is non-zero even if only one of the inputs was non-zero.  Concatenating the bits together (shift+or) is also of course like an OR if we eventually just test for any non-zero bit.  We can't just bitwise AND because `2 & 1 == 0`, unlike `2 && 1`.

---

#### Keeping it in the vector domain

**Horizontal OR of 4 elements takes multiple steps**.

The obvious way is `_mm_movehl_ps` + OR, then another shuffle+OR.  (See [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86) but replace `_mm_add_ps` with `_mm_or_ps`)

But since we don't actually need an exact bitwise-OR when our inputs are compare results, we just care if any element is non-zero.  We can and should think of the vectors as integer, and look at integer instructions like 64-bit element `==`.  One 64-bit element covers/aliases two 32-bit elements.

```
__m128i cmp = _mm_castps_si128(cmpps_result);               // reinterpret: zero instructions
                 // SSE4.1 pcmpeqq 64-bit integer elements
__m128i cmp64 = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(cmp, _mm_setzero_si128());  // -1 if both elements were zero, otherwise 0
__m128i swap =  _mm_shuffle_epi32(cmp64, _MM_SHUFFLE(1,0, 3,2));  // copy and swap, no movdqa instruction needed even without AVX
__m128i bothzero = _mm_and_si128(cmp64, swap);              // both halves have the full result
```

**After this logical inversion, ORing together multiple `bothzero` results** will give you the AND of multiple conditions you're looking for.

Alternatively, [SSE4.1 `_mm_minpos_epu16(cmp64)` (`phminposuw`)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/phminposuw) will tell us in 1 uop (but 5 cycle latency) if either qword is zero.  It will place either `0` or `0xFFFF` in the lowest word (16 bits) of the result in this case.

**If we inverted the original compares, we could use `phminposuw` on that (without `pcmpeqq`) to check if any are zero.**  So basically a horizontal AND across the whole vector.  (Assuming that it's elements of 0 / -1).  I think that's a useful result for inverted inputs.  (And saves us from using `_mm_xor_si128` to flip the bits).

An alternative to `pcmpeqq` (_mm_cmpeq_epi64) would be SSE2 [`psadbw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psadbw) against a zeroed vector to get 0 or non-zero results in the bottom of each 64-bit element.  It won't be a mask, though, it's `0xFF * 8`.  Still, it's always that or 0 so you can still AND it.  And it doesn't invert.

Comment: For the exact use case of the OP you could use the "anding" of `ptest` to save the `orps`, by negating the comparisons, i.e., `_mm_testz_si128(_mm_castps_si128(_mm_cmpngt_ps(x,y)), _mm_castps_si128(_mm_cmpngt_ps(z,w)));`

Comment: To force zeroing `eax` before `set** al` you can return `int` instead of `bool` (not sure how much influence this has once it is inlined): https://godbolt.org/z/axxOo5

Comment: @chtz: IDK, that might help even after inlining.  Worth a try if a false dep causes a bottleneck or reduces ILP.  With good choices of destination registers, spending extra uops on xor-zeroing wouldn't be worth it.  On AMD (no partial-reg renaming), even using `AL` and `AH`, and DL,DH, as separate destinations would be good if there are many vectors, allowing SWAR AND before eventually doing one last horizontal AND with `test al,ah`.  But on Intel that would be bad with partial-register merging uops.

Comment: @chtz: Good idea with inverting the inputs so you need a vertical AND.  But doesn't `testz` still give you a horizontal OR when you need a horizontal AND?  Maybe I'm mixing something up, gtg for lunch right now. 
 Related [Can PTEST be used to test if two registers are both zero or some other condition?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43712243)

Comment: @chtz: You had me convinced for a minute, but I was finding problems commenting the code while making an edit to the answer.  Yeah, vertical-AND / horizontal-NOR doesn't give us all-true or all-false for 2 separate inputs.